# What is the best way to join/merge two tables by column cell matching in Excel?

Tags: excel, join

I've found this [excel add-in to buy](http://www.digdb.com/excel_add_ins/join_merge_tables_lists/) that appears to do what I need, but I'd rather have code that's open to use as I wish. While a GUI is nice, it's not required.

In an attempt to make the question more clear, I'm adding some two sample "input" tables in tab delimited form, and the resulting output table:

**SAMPLE_INPUT_TABLE_01**

```
horse<tab>age<tab>body
a<tab>1<tab>A
b<tab>2<tab>B
b<tab>3<tab>C
c<tab>4<tab>D
e<tab>5<tab>E
f<tab>6<tab>F
```

**SAMPLE_INPUT_TABLE_02**

```
rider<tab>horse<tab>finish<tab>date
xxx<tab>a<tab>yy<tab>zz
xxx<tab>b<tab>yy<tab>zz
xxx<tab>b<tab>yy<tab>zz
xxx<tab>c<tab>yy<tab>zz
xxx<tab>e<tab>yy<tab>zz
xxx<tab>f<tab>yy<tab>zz
```

**SAMPLE_OUTPUT_TABLE_03**

```
rider<tab>horse<tab>finish<tab>date<tab>age<tab>body
xxx<tab>a<tab>yy<tab>zz<tab>1<tab>A
xxx<tab>b<tab>yy<tab>zz<tab>3<tab>C
xxx<tab>b<tab>yy<tab>zz<tab>3<tab>C
xxx<tab>c<tab>yy<tab>zz<tab>4<tab>D
xxx<tab>e<tab>yy<tab>zz<tab>5<tab>E
xxx<tab>f<tab>yy<tab>zz<tab>6<tab>F
```

If it matters, I'm using Office 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: I don't see a question here except for the one in the subject. What exactly are you asking, except for people to go visit the web site for the add-in?

Comment: @Ken White: The question is the question, and the link is to provide info/proof on what is possible. Since it appears you read both the question and visited the link, what is not clear? Thanks

Comment: @Ken White: Added two sample tables for input, and a sample output table -- which should make the question more clear, let me know if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this emulates the example in your link:

[image]

The formulas are:

In I2 (and copied down):

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$C$7,2)
```

In J2 (and copied down:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$C$7,3)
```

Comment: (+1 and selected as answer) -- Thanks for posting working code, updated my sample data to match your answer; since I know you where creating your sample at the same time I added mine. Cheers!

Comment: @blunders Tnx for synchronizing your question! Happy New Year!

Comment: @blunders Here is a trick if you have a lot of columns as a result from the join http://en.allexperts.com/q/Excel-1059/Copying-VLOOKUP-function-multiple.htm

Comment: +1 Cool, thanks. One thing I might add is that it appears your VLOOKUP function needs "false" added as the last parameter; this will force exact matches only. Also, for the multi-column reuse, it appears that if you wrap the column that's being output like this "COLUMN(A1)" in the third parameter, that it will convert the column name to a numeral for VLOOKUP to use; which is only of use if the columns being matched are in the order you need and share the same lookup key; so, for your code example, it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this yesterday, and [vlookup](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/vlookup-function-in-excel-2010/) solved my problem.
Basically, you look for a join value from one of the tables inside the other one,
and then use a column offset to get another column from the same row.
This may become tedious when your tables have many columns, and does not support left join, but may be enough for your use case.